# Loop through each row in dynamic column using Excel Tables and VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I am trying to loop through various elements in a Vertical Excel Table and pass them to a horizontal table using VBA.  The vertical table is a form that contains a list of questions (name,label,value) and the horizontal table will contain columns using the question name from the vertical table.

The code looks something like this:

```
Dim row As Range
Dim rowCount As Integer: rowCount = 1
For Each row In [tbl_QUESTIONS[name]].Rows
  Sheets(ANSWERS).Cells(r,rowCount).Value = row.Value
  rowCount = rowCount + 1
Next
```

My question is, how can modify the table reference and column reference so that they are dynamic?

```
[tbl_QUESTIONS[name]].Rows
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
["tbl_" & tblName & "[" & colName & "]]".Rows
```

But that doesn't seem to work...  Is there a simpler way to reference this using VBA?  I get the feeling that there has to be a way of creating the ListObject out of ["tbl_" & tblName] but I haven't been able to reference 'colName' inside the ListObject or the ListObject.Rows

Any help would be appreciated.

Oh, and I'd like to keep this compatible with Excel 2007 VBA if at all possible.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon **[this link](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/making-a-structured-reference-to-a-table-column-in-vba.13825/)** and it seems to do the trick.

Looks like I can create a range using the following:

```
Dim TBL As Range
Set TBL = Range("tbl_" & tblName & "[" & colName & "]")
```

I'd still like to see a way of keeping the ListObject rather than defining a range, but I'll go with this until I have an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know this by now but since the question has no answer...

use the LisObjects collection to select a listObject and pass that as a parameter to your function/sub